# Visual counter for LaTeX?

Tags: beamer, counters

Does anyone know of a LaTeX package that implements a visual counter similar to the countdown counter of [this context-module](https://github.com/adityam/visualcounter)?
It produces images like this:

[image: countdown counter in context]

However, I would like to stick to LaTeX and `beamer`, so if anyone has used/hacked together something similar, I would appreciate any reference.

I am aware of the progress bar theme, but I would like to add such a circular progressbar to my own theme.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. This is perfectly doable, with TikZ for example: a similar realization is implemented in [the Sobre theme](https://github.com/cedricmauclair/beamer-themes/tree/master/beamer-sobre).

Comment: A [Harvey Balls](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/harveyballs) package was just announced the other day.  Not quite as 'pretty' as the ones in your picture....

Answer (score 25):

If just want to draw it, you might want to check this. I've just fixed some stuff about it (now it checks the parameters given, and sends warning if necessary).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\statuslabel[3][]{%
    \def\scale{#1}
    \ifx\scale\empty\def\scale{1}\fi

    \let\no\relax
    \let\n\relax
    \newcommand \no {#2}
    \newcommand \n {#3}
    \def \colorbef {blue}
    \def \colorat {orange}
    \def \coloraft {black!40}

    \let\stop\relax
    \sbox\z@{\@tempcnta=0\no\relax}\ifdim\wd0>\z@\relax\@latex@warning{Not a number (\#2): \no}\def\stop{1}\fi
    \sbox\z@{\@tempcnta=0\n\relax}\ifdim\wd0>\z@\relax\@latex@warning{Not a number (\#3): \n}\def\stop{1}\fi
    \ifx\stop\relax
        \ifnum\no>\n\@latex@warning{Wrong parameter order?}\def\stop{1}\fi
    \fi

    \ifx\stop\relax
    \else
        \def \no {1}
        \def \n {1}
        \def \colorat {red}
        \def \stop {??}
    \fi

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.1*\scale]

    \def \radiusout {2cm}
    \def \radiusin {1.3cm}
    \ifnum\n=1
        \def \margin {0}
    \else
        \def \margin {25/\n}
    \fi

    \foreach \s in {1,...,\n}
    {
        \node[circle, scale=\scale] at (0,0) {\tiny\stop};
        \fill[\ifnum\s>\no\coloraft\relax\else\ifnum\s<\no\colorbef\else\colorat\fi\fi]
            ({90-360/\n * (\s - 1)-\margin}:\radiusout) arc ({90-360/\n * (\s - 1)-\margin}:{90-360/\n * (\s)+\margin}:\radiusout) --
            ({90-360/\n * (\s)+\margin}:\radiusin) arc ({90-360/\n * (\s)+\margin}:{90-360/\n * (\s - 1)-\margin}:\radiusin);
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

2/8: \statuslabel{2}{8}

6/6: \statuslabel{6}{6}

4/22: \statuslabel{4}{22}

1/1: \statuslabel{1}{1}

4/2 warning and off: \statuslabel{4}{2}

3/7 scale 2x: \statuslabel[2]{3}{7}

\end{document}
```

You can also create an enumeration environment (in a bit hack way):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\statuslabel[3][]{%
    \def\scale{#1}
    \ifx\scale\empty\def\scale{1}\fi

    \let\no\relax
    \let\n\relax
    \newcommand \no {#2}
    \newcommand \n {#3}
    \def \colorbef {blue}
    \def \colorat {orange}
    \def \coloraft {black!40}

    \let\stop\relax
    \sbox\z@{\@tempcnta=0\no\relax}\ifdim\wd0>\z@\relax\@latex@warning{Not a number (\#2): \no}\def\stop{1}\fi
    \sbox\z@{\@tempcnta=0\n\relax}\ifdim\wd0>\z@\relax\@latex@warning{Not a number (\#3): \n}\def\stop{1}\fi
    \ifx\stop\relax
        \ifnum\no>\n\@latex@warning{Wrong parameter order?}\def\stop{1}\fi
    \fi

    \ifx\stop\relax
    \else
        \def \no {1}
        \def \n {1}
        \def \colorat {red}
        \def \stop {??}
    \fi

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.1*\scale]

    \def \radiusout {2cm}
    \def \radiusin {1.3cm}
    \ifnum\n=1
        \def \margin {0}
    \else
        \def \margin {25/\n}
    \fi

    \foreach \s in {1,...,\n}
    {
        \node[circle, scale=\scale] at (0,0) {\tiny\stop};
        \fill[\ifnum\s>\no\coloraft\relax\else\ifnum\s<\no\colorbef\else\colorat\fi\fi]
            ({90-360/\n * (\s - 1)-\margin}:\radiusout) arc ({90-360/\n * (\s - 1)-\margin}:{90-360/\n * (\s)+\margin}:\radiusout) --
            ({90-360/\n * (\s)+\margin}:\radiusin) arc ({90-360/\n * (\s)+\margin}:{90-360/\n * (\s - 1)-\margin}:\radiusin);
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcounter{myenum} % to create unique labels
\newenvironment{myenum}
  {\stepcounter{myenum}
   \edef\nref{\getrefnumber{myenum@\arabic{myenum}}}
   \edef\nref{\expandafter\@firstofone\nref}
   \begin{enumerate}[
     label=\protect\statuslabel{\arabic*}{\nref},
     ref=\arabic*]}
  {\label{myenum@\arabic{myenum}}%
   \end{enumerate}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{myenum}
\item example
\item example
\item example
\end{myenum}
\end{document}
```

References:

- [Can I include the last index inside the label of an enumeration?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140671/can-i-include-the-last-index-inside-the-label-of-an-enumeration)
- [How to use a tikz image as label in enumerate? [duplicate]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140708/how-to-use-a-tikz-image-as-label-in-enumerate)
- [How to use \ref command in the test block of \ifnum?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140775/how-to-use-ref-command-in-the-test-block-of-ifnum)
- [Strange output of \getrefnumber (refcount package) with custom enumeration](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140849/strange-output-of-getrefnumber-refcount-package-with-custom-enumeration)

Comment: That's a very complete code for this kind of pictures, it's been useful for me. Thanks

Answer (score 20):

A solution in Beamer (inspired [@masu answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140643/13304), but with clockwise increments).

It actually can be used both in Beamer or in non-presentation documents: the user selects where it is convenient one or the other option via the key `beamer`. Usually it is set to false allowing the selection of `current` and `total value` parameters. When `beamer=true`, the latter parameters are overridden by the Beamer settings `\insertframenumber` and `\inserttotalframenumber`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifbeamer%
\pgfkeys{/visual counter/.cd,
 thickness/.store in=\thickness,
 thickness=0.4ex,
 radius/.store in=\radius,
 radius=1.5ex,
 segment distance/.store in=\segdist,
 segment distance=8,
 color current frame/.store in=\colcurrframe,
 color current frame=orange,
 color old frame/.store in=\cololdframe,
 color old frame=blue,
 color next frame/.store in=\colnextframe,
 color next frame=gray!30,
 current value/.store in=\currentv,
 current value=1,
 total value/.store in=\totalv,
 total value=5,
 beamer/.is if=beamer,
 beamer/.default=false,
 countdown/.code={
    \begin{tikzpicture}[fill color/.style={}]
    \ifbeamer
     \pgfkeys{/visual counter/.cd, 
       current value=\insertframenumber,
       total value=\inserttotalframenumber,
     }
    \fi
    \def\current{\currentv}
    \def\tot{\totalv}
    \def\radiusout{\radius}
    \def\radiusin{\radius-\thickness}

    \foreach \s[] in {1,...,\tot}
    {
      \ifnum\s>\current%
        \tikzset{fill color/.append style={\colnextframe}}%
      \fi%
      \ifnum\s=\current%
        \tikzset{fill color/.append style={\colcurrframe}}%
      \fi%
      \ifnum\s<\current%
        \tikzset{fill color/.append style={\cololdframe}}%
      \fi%
      \fill[fill color]
        ({90-360/\tot * (\s - 1)-\segdist}:\radiusout) arc 
        ({90-360/\tot * (\s - 1)-\segdist}:{90-360/\tot * (\s)+\segdist}:\radiusout) --
        ({90-360/\tot * (\s)+\segdist}:\radiusin) arc 
        ({90-360/\tot * (\s)+\segdist}:{90-360/\tot * (\s - 1)-\segdist}:\radiusin);
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
 }
}

\newcommand{\setvcoptions}[1]{
\pgfkeys{/visual counter/.cd,#1}
}
\newcommand{\addvisualcounter}{%
\tikz\node[/visual counter/.cd, beamer=true,countdown]{};
}

% new footline with 
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.95\textwidth, ht=2ex,dp=1ex,sep=1ex]{footline}
\hfill%
\addvisualcounter
\end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother

% Let's change some options:
\setvcoptions{
 segment distance=9,
 thickness=0.5ex
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
bla bla bla

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[/visual counter/.cd, 
current value=3, total value=8,
radius=1.5cm, thickness=0.5cm,color current frame=green!80!black,countdown] at (0,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Something else}
This uses the ``beamer'' option so no need to explicitly set the counters:


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yshift=3cm]
\node[/visual counter/.cd, radius=1.25cm, thickness=0.25cm,
beamer=true,
color current frame=green!80!black,
color old frame=magenta!80!violet,
countdown] at (0,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Different title}
bla bla bla

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[/visual counter/.cd, radius=1cm, thickness=0.1cm,
color current frame=cyan!70!blue,
color old frame=magenta!80!violet,
color next frame=orange!50,
current value=6,
total value=24,
countdown] at (0,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Another one}
bla bla bla

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[/visual counter/.cd, radius=1.25cm, thickness=0.5cm,
color current frame=red!70!orange,
color old frame=red!70!black,
color next frame=orange!80,
segment distance=3,
current value=6,
total value=10,
countdown] at (0,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Final}
bla bla bla

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[/visual counter/.cd, radius=1.25cm, thickness=0.25cm,
color current frame=red!70!orange,
color old frame=red!70!black,
beamer=true,
countdown] at (0,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: In terms of the interface, this is closest to the visualcounter module. However, the visualcounter module works with any counter (page, section, itemize, enumeration); so that the current and last values are calculated automatically. I don't know if there is an easy way to do that in LaTeX.

Comment: @Aditya: in principle also my solution can work with any counter; in Beamer is easy as it is quite straightforward to access current and total values. With other counters, the problem is only the total value: I guess can be possible to compute it from aux files, but it's just an intuition.

Answer (score 13):

It is just for fun with PSTricks and not a complete solution. The remaining part should be easy to add.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\SpecialCoor
\psset{linewidth=.5}
\def\Atom#1#2{%
    \multido{\i=0+1}{#1}{%
        \psarcn[linecolor=#2](0,0){1.5}{!115 \i\space 60 mul sub}{!65 \i\space 60 mul sub}}}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=0+1}{7}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
    \Atom{6}{lightgray}
    \Atom{\i}{blue}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Overwriting existing gray cells will blue cells does not look pretty when using transparent colors. Therefore it is better to draw the blue and the gray cells separately.