# How to use \ref command in the test block of \ifnum?

Tags: cross-referencing, conditionals

Is there a way to use `\ref{}` inside the test part of `\ifnum`. The following example runs into an error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \caption{ex}
    \label{tab:ex}
\end{table}

\def\a{\ref{tab:ex}}
\ifnum\a>0 y\else n\fi

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the command `\getrefnumber` from the package [`refcount`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/refcount) and define `\a` as

```
\def\a{\getrefnumber{tab:ex}}
```

At this point change your MWE to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \caption{ex}
    \label{tab:ex}
\end{table}

\def\a{\getrefnumber{tab:ex}}
\ifnum\a>0 y\else n\fi

\end{document}
```

and you will get what you want.