# Changing page to pages if more than one page

Tags: conditionals, lastpage

At the beginning of my document, I need to list the total number of pages in the document. I've got a system that works most of the time (see below), but if the document only has one page, then my document reads "1 pages," which is unfortunate. Is there anyway to have it correct read "1 page" if there is one page, and "n pages" if there are n > 1 pages? My document needs to compile using pdflatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\begin{document}
\pageref{LastPage} pages
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See also [How to use \ref command in the test block of \ifnum?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140775/how-to-use-ref-command-in-the-test-block-of-ifnum/140783?s=3|0.2376#140783)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{refcount}% must go before ]astpage
\usepackage{lastpage}

\begin{document}
\expandafter\ifnum\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}>1\relax \pageref{LastPage} pages
\else \pageref{LastPage} page
\fi

\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With `zref` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[totpages,user]{zref}

\newcommand{\totpages}{\ifnum\ztotpages=1 1 page \else  \ztotpages\ pages \fi}

\begin{document}
\totpages
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm going to use the solution with the lastpage package because that is what I am currently using, but this solution is good, too!

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
\label{LastPage}%
\protected@write\@auxout{}%
{\string\gdef\string\mtpages{page%
\ifx\@begindvi\@empty s\fi}}
}\makeatother
\begin{document}
\pageref{LastPage} \mtpages{}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```