# Strange output of \getrefnumber (refcount package) with custom enumeration

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumerate, enumitem

Can someone help my why are the two warning messages different syntactically (when they seem to be generated the same way)?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{refcount}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\statuslabel[1]{%
    \def\nref{\getrefnumber{#1}}
    \@latex@warning{Not a number (\#3): \nref}
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcounter{enumerateof} % to create unique labels
\newenvironment{enumerateof}
  {\stepcounter{enumerateof}
   \begin{enumerate}[
     label=\protect\statuslabel{enof@\arabic{enumerateof}},
     ref=\arabic*]}
  {\label{enof@\arabic{enumerateof}}%
   \end{enumerate}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerateof}
    \item example
\end{enumerateof}

\begin{table}
    \caption{example}
    \label{tab@ex}
\end{table}

\protect\statuslabel{tab@ex}

\end{document}
```

Warning messages:

```
LaTeX Warning: Not a number (\#3): {1} on input line 27.
LaTeX Warning: Not a number (\#3): 1 on input line 35.
```

Where does those curly braces come from? How can I remove them (define something which is equal to the content of the braces}?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `enumitem` package adds them there. To remove them, you can (quite safely) do as here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{refcount}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\statuslabel[1]{%
    \edef\nref{\getrefnumber{#1}}
    \edef\nref{\expandafter\@firstofone\nref}
    \@latex@warning{Not a number (\#3): \nref}
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcounter{enumerateof} % to create unique labels
\newenvironment{enumerateof}
  {\stepcounter{enumerateof}
   \begin{enumerate}[
     label=\protect\statuslabel{enof@\arabic{enumerateof}},
     ref=\arabic*]}
  {\label{enof@\arabic{enumerateof}}%
   \end{enumerate}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerateof}
    \item example
\end{enumerateof}

\begin{table}
    \caption{example}
    \label{tab@ex}
\end{table}

\protect\statuslabel{tab@ex}

\end{document}
```

The point is that if `\nref` expands to let's say `123` at the first step, then `\@firstofone` takes `1` as its argument and returns `1`, leaving `23` in the stream. And if it's `{123}`, then `\@firstofone` takes it all and removes the braces.

Comment: Do you think it is a bug in `enumitem`?

Comment: I would not call this exactly a bug. It is a property of the package, probably given by the fact that the author didn't consider someone doing this. I'll contact the package author and ask him for his opinion, he might even answer here I think.

Comment: Thanks. I thought the same. Even I didn't consider someone doing this. :)

Comment: For the big picture, my task wasn't exactly this. I used your solution as a part in [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140643/36821) for a different topic.

Comment: It's a feature, in fact -- `ref` is supposed to print a string (and also `\arabic` for that matter), which may include formating commands, and which should be local. (But I discovered sometimes there is an extra pair of redundant braces.)

Comment: (MUCH later) I discovered that hyperref provides its own \getrefnumber which IS compatible with enumitem.