# Abbreviate \ref within same section

Tags: cross-referencing

Given sample code

```
\section{One}
\begin{enumerate}
\item\label{li:one}
\end{enumerate}

\section{Two}
\begin{enumerate}
\item\label{li:two}
\end{enumerate}

I am referencing \ref{li:one} and \ref{li:two}
```

I would like this to render as

**I am referencing (A.1) and (1)**

That is, I want to include the section number when referencing labels from another section, but omit it for labels within the same section. How can I do this?

**EDIT**: I am using `enumitem` as well as `hyperref`

Comment: Are you using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)? Does this only hold for lists inside sections?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208958/how-to-change-the-appearance-of-ref-depending-on-where-its-called-relative-to

Comment: @Werner Yes, I am using enumitem

Comment: @JohnKormylo that seems pretty complex (maybe that's unavoidable)… is there no way to do it with `\labelformat`?

Comment: @YuriSulyma: Are you using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) or any other cross-referencing package? This is important to know, as they tend to modify `\ref` and may require special handling to accommodate your request.

Comment: Potential duplicate: [How to make the enumeration of theorem-like environments indipendent from cross-referencing in a particular way](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262652/5001)

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using `hyperref`, you can use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% to demonstrate compatability
\usepackage{xstring}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}% is this the default?

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\refitem}[1]% #1 = label name
{\@ifundefined{r@#1}{??}{\begingroup%
  \edef\temp{\expandafter\detokenize\ref{#1}}%
  \StrCut{\temp}{.}\tempsection\tempitem%
  \if\thesection\tempsection\relax(\tempitem)%
  \else(\tempsection.\tempitem)%
  \fi
\endgroup}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{One}
\begin{enumerate}[ref=\thesection.\arabic*]
\item\label{li:one}
\end{enumerate}

\noindent I am referencing  \refitem{li:one} and \refitem{li:two}.

\section{Two}
\begin{enumerate}[ref=\thesection.\arabic*]
\item\label{li:two}
\end{enumerate}


\noindent I am referencing \refitem{li:one} and \refitem{li:two}.
\end{document}
```

[image: cropped page]

If you are using `hyperref`, you will need to replace the above `\refitem` with:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\def\autoref#1#2#3#4#5\@nil{\edef\anchor{#3}}
\newcommand{\getrefanchor}[1]{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\autoref
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@gobble
    \csname r@#1\endcsname{}\@nil}

\newcommand{\refitem}[1]% #1 = label name
{\@ifundefined{r@#1}{??}{\begingroup%
  \edef\temp{\expandafter\detokenize\getrefnumber{#1}}%
  \StrCut{\temp}{.}\tempsection\tempitem%
  \getrefanchor{#1}% saves as \anchor
  \if\thesection\tempsection\relax\hyperlink{\anchor}{(\tempitem)}%
  \else\hyperlink{\anchor}{(\tempsection.\tempitem)}%
  \fi
\endgroup}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: You define \getrefnu**mm**ber but later call \getrefnumber --- which should it be? When I change it to \getrefnummber I get the error "Argument of \@car has an extra }"

Comment: @Yuri Sulyma - Thank you, I didn't even notice. It seems that hyperref provides its own \getrefnumber (presumably due to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140849/strange-output-of-getrefnumber-refcount-package-with-custom-enumeration…)