# LuaLaTeX error when compiling visual counter

Tags: beamer, luatex, persian

I asked a question about visual counters in `beamer`, for which I got [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171389/special-circled-frame-number-in-beamer/171403?noredirect=1#). Now I need to compile it by LuaLaTeX in order to use the package `luapersian`(below code), but it returns some errors.
Luapersina can be downloaded from [this link](http://www.mediafire.com/download/rfphbu45ecmnm4h/luapersian.rar).

‎

```
‎\documentclass{beamer}‎
‎\usepackage{lmodern}‎
‎\usepackage{tikz}‎
‎\usetikzlibrary{calc}‎

‎\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}‎

‎\pgfkeys{/visual counter/.cd‎,
 ‎thickness/.store in=\thickness‎,
 ‎thickness=0.4ex‎,
 ‎radius/.store in=\radius‎,
 ‎radius=1.5ex‎,
 ‎segment distance/.store in=\segdist‎,
 ‎segment distance=8‎,
 ‎color current frame/.store in=\colcurrframe‎,
 ‎color current frame=orange‎,
 ‎color old frame/.store in=\cololdframe‎,
 ‎color old frame=blue‎,
 ‎color next frame/.store in=\colnextframe‎,
 ‎color next frame=gray!30‎,
 ‎color page number/.store in=\colpagenum‎,
 ‎color page number=white‎,
 ‎current value/.store in=\currentv‎,
 ‎current value=1‎,
 ‎total value/.store in=\totalv‎,
 ‎total value=2‎,
 ‎circled page number/.code={‎
    ‎\begin{tikzpicture}[fill color/.style={}]‎
     ‎\pgfkeys{/visual counter/.cd‎, 
       ‎current value=\insertframenumber‎,
       ‎total value=\inserttotalframenumber‎,
     }
    ‎\pgfmathtruncatemacro\current{\currentv+1}‎
    ‎\def\tot{\totalv}‎
    ‎\def\radiusout{\radius}‎
    ‎\def\radiusin{\radius-\thickness}‎

    ‎\foreach \s in {1,...,\tot}‎
    {
      ‎\ifnum\s>\current%‎
        ‎\tikzset{fill color/.append style={\colnextframe}}%‎
      ‎\fi%‎
      ‎\ifnum\s=\current%‎
        ‎\tikzset{fill color/.append style={\colcurrframe}}%‎
      ‎\fi%‎
      ‎\ifnum\s<\current%‎
        ‎\tikzset{fill color/.append style={\cololdframe}}%‎
      ‎\fi%‎
      ‎\fill[fill color]‎
        ‎({90-360/\tot * (\s‎ - ‎1)-\segdist}:\radiusout) arc‎ 
        ‎({90-360/\tot * (\s‎ - ‎1)-\segdist}:{90-360/\tot * (\s)+\segdist}:\radiusout)‎ --
        ‎({90-360/\tot * (\s)+\segdist}:\radiusin) arc‎ 
        ‎({90-360/\tot * (\s)+\segdist}:{90-360/\tot * (\s‎ - ‎1)-\segdist}:\radiusin);‎
        % ‎new addition‎
        ‎\node[inner sep=0pt,text=\colpagenum] at (0,0){\insertframenumber};‎
    }
    ‎\end{tikzpicture}‎
 ‎}‎,
}

% ‎new footline with‎ 
‎\setbeamertemplate{footline}{‎
‎\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.95\textwidth‎, ‎ht=2ex,dp=1ex,sep=1ex]{footline}‎
‎\hfill%‎
‎\tikz\node[/visual counter/.cd‎,
‎segment distance=-2pt‎,
‎radius=0.5cm‎, ‎thickness=0.5cm‎,
‎color old frame=orange!50‎,
‎color current frame=cyan!80!gray!50‎,
‎color next frame=cyan!80!gray!50‎,
‎circled page number‎,
‎]{};‎
‎\end{beamercolorbox}‎
}‎

‎\usepackage{luapersian}‎

‎\begin{document}‎


‎\begin{frame}

‎\end{frame}‎

‎\end{document}‎
```

Comment: Please give us some code. I don't use Persian and don't want to find out how to do that in LaTeX just in order to help here with some compilation issue. And what are the errors?

Comment: Yes, please, edit your post and include all the relevant TeX codes, otherwise we are wildly guessing what might go wrong.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I edited the post, please see again.

Comment: Your example document fails to compile (even without `luapersian`); something seems to be wrong. Does it compile for you as is (without loading `luapersian`)?

Comment: yes, just compile it using:                                    lualatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=-1 %.tex

Answer (score 1):

> **Caveat emptor** I don't have `\usepackage{luapersian}`, so I only tried to compile with `lualatex`

Your visible code looks fine, but when copying from your question above there where tons of invisible characters in front of after the visible text. After removing all of them, you example compiles fine with `lualatex`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\pgfkeys{/visual counter/.cd,
thickness/.store in=\thickness,
thickness=0.4ex,
radius/.store in=\radius,
radius=1.5ex,
segment distance/.store in=\segdist,
segment distance=8,
color current frame/.store in=\colcurrframe,
color current frame=orange,
color old frame/.store in=\cololdframe,
color old frame=blue,
color next frame/.store in=\colnextframe,
color next frame=gray!30,
color page number/.store in=\colpagenum,
color page number=white,
current value/.store in=\currentv,
current value=1,
total value/.store in=\totalv,
total value=2,
circled page number/.code={
\begin{tikzpicture}[fill color/.style={}]
\pgfkeys{/visual counter/.cd, 
current value=\insertframenumber,
total value=\inserttotalframenumber,
}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\current{\currentv+1}
\def\tot{\totalv}
\def\radiusout{\radius}
\def\radiusin{\radius-\thickness}

\foreach \s in {1,...,\tot}
{
\ifnum\s>\current%
\tikzset{fill color/.append style={\colnextframe}}%
\fi%
\ifnum\s=\current%
\tikzset{fill color/.append style={\colcurrframe}}%
\fi%
\ifnum\s<\current%
\tikzset{fill color/.append style={\cololdframe}}%
\fi%
\fill[fill color]
({90-360/\tot * (\s - 1)-\segdist}:\radiusout) arc 
({90-360/\tot * (\s - 1)-\segdist}:{90-360/\tot * (\s)+\segdist}:\radiusout) --
({90-360/\tot * (\s)+\segdist}:\radiusin) arc 
({90-360/\tot * (\s)+\segdist}:{90-360/\tot * (\s - 1)-\segdist}:\radiusin);
% new addition
\node[inner sep=0pt,text=\colpagenum] at (0,0){\insertframenumber};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
},
}

% new footline with 
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.95\textwidth, ht=2ex,dp=1ex,sep=1ex]{footline}
\hfill%
\tikz\node[/visual counter/.cd,
segment distance=-2pt,
radius=0.5cm, thickness=0.5cm,
color old frame=orange!50,
color current frame=cyan!80!gray!50,
color next frame=cyan!80!gray!50,
circled page number,
]{};
\end{beamercolorbox}
}

%\usepackage{luapersian}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
abc
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
abc
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
abc
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]